# XCode4: Product->Archive. Do I need to have device to archive the app?

Tags: xcode4, app-store

I want to archive the app and then transmit it to the app store. I selected menu: run on iOS device, but did not connect my real iPhone. The app archived file and said that it is ok. Do I need to have the device to archive the app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. You don't need to connect your device to archive it. As long as you select iOS Device, the Archive option comes available. This creates an archive in your Organiser, which you can then Validate and Submit to the App Store.

Good luck.